# Ability to switch between Ruby on Rails versions, one from rbenv, other from rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rvm, centos7, rbenv

I first used rbenv to install ruby ver 2.2 and Rails ver 4.2 on Linux CentOS 7, then used rvm to install ruby ver 2.4 and rails ver 5.2. Is there a way to switch between these easily or do they both have to be installed using the same method for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing RVM and installing the newer versions with rbenv instead. Having both versions installed with the same method allowed it to be easy to switch when needed. The shims automatically use the correct Rails versions for each project respectively. As far as I can tell, the Rails versions are locked in with whichever one you started the project with. You can switch the Ruby version for each project by using:

```
# rbenv local 2.4.1
```

I chose rbenv over rvm because I read several articles of people praising rbenv's lightweight approach and ease of use over rvm.

NOTE: the "#" character is the beginning of the command line in Linux CentOS 7, NOT a character that you type in.

EDIT: Thank you guys for the recommendations, though. It got me to look more into using rbenv vs. rvm.

Answer (score 1):

Better you can use rvm. Rvm is the better tool to switch between many versions with the command

> `rvm use ruby-2.5.1` or `rvm use 2.5.1`

For list out all rvm just use

> rvm list

within rvm, you can manage the versions nicely no need of rbenv here.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer RVM, it's easy to switch between version, also you can use multiple rails version for that ruby easily

install rvm, install ruby and create a gemset with `rvm use 2.4@rails_5_2 --create` will create a gemset with name `rails_5_2`

for switching between versions. I use `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files in my project so i don't need to specify version all the time

in the .ruby-version file write the ruby version

`2.4`

and inside ruby-gemset write gemset name

`rails_5_2`

so whenever you will run the project it takes ruby and rails version from there

you can create this two file manually or you can run this command in terminal  from your application directory which will create this two files

`rvm --ruby-version use 2.4@rails_5_2`

Comment: Thank you. Where would you put these ruby version and gemset files?

Comment: in project folder, i mean in your application folder, with gitignore and other files

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to this. So you make these files just in the folder named "app" and not in a subfolder in there? Also, what file types are these and you just put one line of code in there?

Comment: no problem, not in rails app folder, just go to your applicaiton(your project like my_app) folder and create this two file, yes with one line, your ruby version and gemset name, this are text file